# Wrong reputation calculation for old posts from Stack Overflow in Russian

Tags: bug, reputation, russian-stackoverflow

I found some users which have reputation for actions which ther couldn't did. 
E.g. user [Deleted](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7905/deleted?tab=profile) earns `+2` rep for [accepting answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/7905/deleted?tab=reputation) for the question [Как организовать обратный SSH-туннель для стороннего пользователя?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/311412/):

> [image: rep+2]

But that question was asked by a different user [Anton Shevtsov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3274/anton-shevtsov). Moreover this user earns `+15` rep for [accepting his own answer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/3274/anton-shevtsov?tab=reputation)!

> [image: rep+15]

Probably this happend due to unperfect posts migration from the old DB into the new one. But I'm pretty sure that such reputations should be fixed.

Comment: I think this is one that should be asked on meta.ru.so. I wonder if there was a question merge involved here. Also what do you mean that you think it was "due to not perfect posts migration from old DB into new one"?

Comment: @ChrisF as far as I know old questions was hosted on different site (hashcode.ru). Now these posts are on ruSO data base. And hashcode.ru is forwarded to ruSO.